# Python infinite recursion with formula

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
### Run the code below and understand the error messages
### Fix the code to sum integers from 1 up to k
### 

def f(k):
    return f(k-1) + k
print(f(10))
```

I am confused on how to fix this code while using recursion, I keep getting the error messages
***[Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded***
Is there a simple way to fix this without using any while loops or creating more than 1 variable?

Comment: This function always calls itself, resulting in an infinite recursion. At some point an actual value should be returned. In this case some if-then-else magic is needed. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursion should have a `termination condition`, i.e. the `base case`. When your variable attains that value there are **no more recursive function calls**.
e.g. in your code,

```
def f(k):
    if(k == 1): 
        return k
    return f(k-1) + k
print(f(10))
```

we define the base case 1, if you want to take the sum of values from n to 1. You can put any other number, positive or negative there, if you want the sum to extend upto that number. e.g. maybe you want to take sum from n to -3, then base case would be k == -3.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have optimized tail recursion. You **f** function call **k** time. If k is very big number then Python trow RecursionError. You can see what is limit of recursion via [sys.getrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) and change via [sys.setrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit). But changing limit is not good idea. Instead of changing you can change your code logic or pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion never terminates.  You could try:

```
def f(k):
    return k if k < 2 else f(k-1) + k
print(f(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working out the sum of all of all numbers from 1 to 10 which in essence returns the 10th triangular number. Eg.  [the number of black circles in each triangle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/First_six_triangular_numbers.svg)

Using the formula [on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000217) gives you this as your code.

```
def f(k):
    return int(k*(k+1)/2)
print(f(10))
```

How do we know int() doesn't break this? k and k + 1 are adjacent numbers and one of them must have a factor of two so this formula will always return an integer if given an integer.